# Setting the same x-scale but different x-limits for adjacent subplots matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to create a figure with three bar plots side by side. These bar plots have different yscales, but the data is fundamentally similar so I'd like all the bars to have the same width.
The only way I was able to get the bars to have the exact same width was by using sharex when creating the subplots, in order to keep the same x scale.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

BigData = [[100,300],[400,200]]
MediumData = [[40, 30],[50,20],[60,50],[30,30]]
SmallData = [[3,2],[11,3],[7,5]]
data = [BigData, MediumData, SmallData]
colors = ['#FC766A','#5B84B1']

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(30,5), sharex=True)
subplot = 0
for scale in data:
    for type in range(2):
        bar_x = [x + type*0.2 for x in range(len(scale))]
        bar_y = [d[type] for d in scale]
        axs[subplot].bar(bar_x,bar_y, width = 0.2, color = colors[type])
        
    subplot += 1
plt.show()
```

This creates this figure:

[image: figure]

The problem with this is that the x-limits of the plot are also shared, leading to unwanted whitespace. I've tried setting the x-bounds after the fact, but it doesn't seem to override sharex. Is there a way to make the bars have the same width, without each subplot also being the same width?

Additionally, is there a way to create such a plot (one with different y scales to depending on the size of the data) without having to sort the data manually beforehand, like shown in my code?

Thanks!

Comment: Please focus on one problem per post.  For your issue, it’s not entirely clear what you want.  If you want the axes the same widths, and the bars the same widths,  but the x limits different, then adjust the widths of the bars in proportion to the width of the x limit.

Comment: If instead you want the same xscale but different width axes, you can use gridspec_kw={‘width_ratios’:[a,b,c]} where you calculate a,b and c

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity Jody! I'm looking to have equal bar widths across the whole figure, with different limits in order to remove the whitespace you see in the picture. I've tried the width_ratios method, where I used the number of bars in each section to get the proper ratios [2,4,3]. That created [this](https://i.imgur.com/l4toyTf.jpeg) result. This is better in terms of white space, but the bars are still of slightly different widths. Is there a better way to calculate the ratios? Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: I think that should work except the ratios are not 2 4 3. You can get the width in data space from ax.get_xlim and use the difference as the relative widths.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you so much, you have made my life a lot easier. Only problem is that get_xlim only returns the right values if I don't set the spacing, meaning I have to run the program without width_ratios first to get the right numbers, then again with my new ratios to get a nice looking plot. Is there a way change the gridspec keywords AFTER the plot has been created? Or is the simplest thing to do just run the plot twice within the program.
Again thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Jody Klymak for help finding this solution! I thought I should document it for future users.

We can make use of the 'width_ratios' GridSpec parameter. Unfortunately there's no way to specify these ratios after we've already drawn a graph, so the best way I found to implement this is to write a function that creates a dummy graph, and measures the x-limits from that graph:

```
def getXRatios(data, size):
    phig, aks = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=size)
    subplot = 0
    for scale in data:
        for type in range(2):
            bar_x = [x + type*0.2 for x in range(len(scale))]
            bar_y = [d[type] for d in scale]
            aks[subplot].bar(bar_x,bar_y, width = 0.2)
        subplot += 1
    ratios = [aks[i].get_xlim()[1] for i in range(3)]
    plt.close(phig)
    return ratios
```

This is essentially identical to the code that creates the **actual** figure, with the cosmetic aspects removed, as all we want from this dummy figure is the x-limits of the graph (something we can't get from our actual figure as we need to define those limits before we start in order to solve the problem).

Now all you need to do is call this function when you're creating your subplots:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(40,5), gridspec_kw = {'width_ratios':getXRatios(data,(40,5))})
```

As long as your XRatio function creates your graph in the same way your actual graph does, everything should work! Here's my [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cRqe.png) using this solution.

To save space you could re-purpose the getXRatios function to also construct your final graph, by calling itself in the arguments and giving an option to return either the ratios or the final figure. I couldn't be bothered.